# Laravel Blade: If php code is wrapped with a display none, is it still run?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to change the `display` fields from javascript.  If a user selects from a drop down to show only in-stock items, I grab the `id` of the `div` and change the display from `none` to `block`.  Is there any issue with it doing this way?  Since the php code is not a query, I'm assuming it shouldn't be an issue if all the foreach statements get run and then their visibility controlled by the `display` on the div.

```
 <div style="display:none" id = "no-filter">
    @foreach ($collection->products('no-filter') as $product)
        @include('prod-list')
    @endforeach
</div>

 <div style="display:none" id = "sale">
    @foreach ($collection->products('sale') as $product)
        @include('prod-list')
    @endforeach
</div>

<div style="display:none" id = "in-stock">
    @foreach ($collection->products('in-stock') as $product)
        @include('prod-list')
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Then where is your select and jquery code?

Comment: It will run. You are using just css to protect the showing result.

Comment: PHP is server-side, CSS/display client-side. It will be run no matter what, on the server, sent to the client, where you show/hide your divs.

Comment: Yes, it will run in your view file as long as it is server side code and you are just hiding the some element of the html as per your need!!